# Event displayed twice in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In my Calendar,I have two kinds of events.

1.Ordinary Events

2.Holiday Events

I am using 'eventSources' to show the events in the calendar from my database.

```
eventSources: ["/calendar/show_events","/calendar/show_holidays"]
```

The Holiday Events are given full background color with title displayed at the middle. For that to achieve, I use 'eventAfterRender'

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
element.append(event.title);
}
```

So that works fine. Now, The Normal Events are listed/displayed twice in a cell. Can Anyone tell me why am i getting like this. I only want the events not to get duplicated.
My calendar sample image is:-

[image: Picture showing two type of events]

Comment: the normal event looks displayed once, but it's the title who is duplicate, right? (look your html code for check it)

Comment: A.Rossi, yes my title is duplicated..why?

Comment: @Keynes because for non-background events the title is displayed automatically by fullCalendar I think. It looks like maybe your holidays are background-type events (as far as fullCalendar is concerned). So your afterRender code needs to check which type of event it's dealing with. Looking at http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/ I think you can check the event's "rendering" property